# Good D-module is induced by coherent O-module?

Tags: d-modules, analytic-d-modules

Let $X$ be a **compact** complex manifold. In Definition 4.24, p.78  of *D-modules and Microlocal Calculus* (by Kashiwara), a coherent $D_X$-module $F$ is called **good** if there is a directed family $\{G_i\}_i$ of coherent $O_X$-submodules of $F$ such that $F=\sum_iG_i$.

From the first paragraph of the proof of Theorem 4.25, it seems that

"For every good $D_X$-module $M$, there is a coherent $O_X$-submodule $F\subset M$ such that $M=D_XF$. "

I tried to prove this but failed. My question is: does every good $D_X$-module is induced by a coherent $O_X$-module, i.e., is the statement in last paragraph is true?

For $M\in Coh(D_X)$, we show that the following are equivalent

1.there is a coherent $O_X$-submodule $F\subset M$ with $M=D_XF$;

2.$M$ admits a good filtration $\{M_v\}_{v\in \mathbb{Z}}$;

3.$M$ is good

By 1.4.10 p.26 of Analytic D-modules and Applications, 1 implies 2.

2 implies 3: Assume 2. By 1.4.6, p.25 of Analytic D-modules and Applications, each $M_v$ is coherent $O_X$-submodule of $M$. Moreover, the family $\{M_v\}_{v\in \mathbb{Z}}$ is increasing, hence directed. Then  $M=\cup_{v\in \mathbb{Z}}M_v=\sum_{v\in \mathbb{Z}}M_v$ is good.

3 implies 1: Say $M=\sum_{i\in I}G_i$, where $\{G_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a directed family of coherent $O_X$-submodules of $F$. Then $M=colim_iG_i=colim_iD_XG_i$.
Now that $M$ is finite type $D_X$-module, by EGA1, p.46, 5.2.3, there is $i_0\in I$ such that $M=D_XG_{i_0}$, then we take $F=G_{i_0}$.

However, the above equivalence seems weird to me. If it is true, we don't need to introduce the notion of "good", but simply say "admitting a good filtration over each compact subset".

Comment: In the analytic setting, a coherent D-module always admits a local good filtration, but it may not admit a global good filtration. I think this is the point of defining "good D-modules". In the algebraic setting, coherence is equivalent to existence of a good filtration.